# How can I list all available product attributes and terms using WooCommerce REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to get all product attributes by WooCommerce REST API using the following code:

```
$current_attributes = $woocommerce->get('products/attributes');
```

However I always receive up to 10 attributes maximum.

I tried a several variants like:

```
$current_attributes = $woocommerce->get('products/attributes', ['filter[limit]' => -1]);
$current_attributes = $woocommerce->get('products/attributes', ['filter[per_page]' => 9999]);
etc.
```

None of these works.

How can I get all product attributes (and later similarly all attributes terms) without the obvious limit for 10?

PS: *I really need to list ALL attributes and ALL terms and not only those attached to a specific product.*

Answer (score 0):

I had used **`wc/v3/products/attributes`**

Invoke a simple **GET** Request: `

> `https://hostname.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes?consumer_key=YOUR_KEY&consumer_secret=YOUR_KEY``

For more info, you can find API spec from https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#list-all-product-attributes

Answer (score 0):

To get more results when making a request to the WooCommerce API, you can use the `per_page` parameter. This parameter determines how many results will be returned per page.

For example, if you want to get 50 results, you can make the following request:

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes/<id>/terms/?per_page=50
```

Keep in mind that WooCommerce usually has a maximum limit for `per_page`, which is usually 100. If there are more than 100 terms for the attribute, you will need to make multiple paginated requests and use the page parameter to get subsequent results.

For example, to get terms 101-200 you would use:

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes/<id>/terms/?per_page=100&page=2
```

Hope this helps.